# How do I silence an error in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to run diff in a makefile and catch the output,

```
test:
     diff a b > tmp
```

but diff returns non-zero if it catches any differences.

Make interprets the non-zero return code as an error, and even if I ignore the error using -diff, it still prints a warning.

```
makefile:7: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: [test] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Can I make it shut up?

Comment: put a '-' in front of the command that you want to ignore.  Change   `diff a b > tmp` to  `-diff a b > tmp`.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure your recipe returns 0 (success) even if the diff command doesn't.  Something like:

```
test:
        diff a b > tmp || true
```